# How to print map with list as value, which grows as every list element will have their own values and furthermore? (Java)

Tags: java, list, recursion, arraylist, hashmap

The issue is that I must add a for-loop as my tree grows. So, the basic idea is that I have a tree which has branches, and those branches could have more branches as it grows in the application. The issue is that as the branch grows, I have to add more for loop.
[Tree Strut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc6or.png)

So, if you see Gen1 have three branches GenTest1, GenTest2, GenTest3. Later GenTest1 have two more branches 321 and MAT00000000000630, further GenTest2 have branch 123 and 123 also have 21 as a branch.
So, this grows more the branches more the for loop.

Implementation
[The idea of how I am implementing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1s8s.png)

```
    parent = new Map<String,List<String>>;

        for (Map.Entry i : parent.entrySet()) {
            key = i.getKey();
            valueList = (List<String>) i.getValue();
            S.O.P("Key: "+
                    key +
                    " & Value: " +
                    valueList);

            for (String child: valueList)
            {
                parent = Map(child.get(0)) //Please don't worry about how the string value is converted into Map I did with my helper classes.
                        

                for(Map.Entry j : parent.entrySet())
                {
                    key = j.getKey();
                    valueList = (List<String>) j.getValue();

                    S.O.P("2ndKey: "+
                            key +
                            " & 2ndValue: " +
                            valueList);
                }

            }
        }
```

You see I can retrieve the branch of GenTest1 and GenTest2.
But in GenTest2 there is 123 and for 123 I must use for loop again.

I know recursion is the best option but, I am having a problem achieving it.

Ok the output should be like this
Gen1
GenTest1
321
MAT000000000628
GenTest2
123
21
GenTest3

Comment: You *cannot* do this for general trees without either recursion or an additional holding structure (a stack or queue). Recursion uses the program stack as a stack, and can be avoided by using an actual in-a-variable stack.

Comment: Ok but if you think I am looping for loop, again and again, is there any way I can for while loop call this for loop again.

Comment: Your code does not compile, and you cannot convert a String into a Map easily. Can you either show an example input (so we can see how a full example tree looks in Java code) or fix the code so that it at least compiles?

Comment: Hey Please check now, if this can help

Comment: Hmm, I still don't understand how you can know if a WTPart has more parts in it, that is, if it is a leaf-node or a tree-branch that can have other leaf-nodes or tree-branches underneath.

Comment: So, run the loop on each of the branches once we get null, then it will not move further. 
But the issue is it will be hardcoded and for every new branch I must add for loop again, which make no sense.

Please see both the images it will help you.

Comment: See my answer. Get a proper `children()` and `isLeaf()` implemented, and then it is very easy indeed to use recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple recursion which I made complex through iteration.

```
Map<String, List<String>> parent;
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> i : root.entrySet()) {
        logger.debug("Root"+" "+i.getKey());
        for (String j : i.getValue()) {
            parent = Map(j.get(0)); // using my helper class
            build(parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need some like this...

```java
private void print(Map<String, List<String>> parent) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> i : parent.entrySet()) {
            String key = i.getKey();
            List<String> valueList = i.getValue();
            System.out.println("Key: " +
                    key +
                    " & Value: " +
                    valueList);

            for (String child : valueList) {
                print(Map(child.get(0))); // you helped method
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Again this will only get me the first level of branch

Answer (score 0):

In the Java, there is a standard [TreeNode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeNode.html) interface that you should consider implementing within `WTPart`. Its main methods are

```
 n.children()  // equivalent to your MBOMH.getPCP(MBOMH.getPP(n).get(0))
 n.isLeaf()    // MISSING in your code, to know when to stop digging
 n.getParent() // this you do not need for your specific case
```

For a tree of `MyNode extends TreeNode` are used, you can print contents recursively by implementing a print function in `MyNode`, as follows:

```
 public void print() {
     System.out.println(this); // calls toString() to print self
     if (isLeaf()) {
        return;                // avoids trying to print children if none there
     }
     // TreeNode's children() returns an enumeration; returning a List
     // would make it easier to iterate with for (MyNode n : children())
     for (Enumeration<MyNode> e=children(); e.hasNextElement(); /**/) {
         e.next().print();
     } 
 }
```

So my suggestion is to implement an `isLeaf()`, and while you are at it, implement a `children()` method that is less ugly than `MechatronicBOMHelper.getPartentChildPart(MechatronicBOMHelper.getPartProp(child).get(0))`. Since you have a helper class, you can consider having a `MechatronicBOMHelper.childrenOf(child)` instead of having a `child.getChildren()`, but the second is more OO-like.

Comment: if you can show me with example will be good

Comment: I cannot suggest an `isLeaf()` for your WTPart, as I do not know what it looks like. Nor can I suggest an implementation of `children()` for WTPart, which would ideally return a list.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you can do it with using string key and string list

Let say you can output 
Root
>>child1
    >>>>child1a
    >>>>child1b

Comment: It doesn't matter if you can do it with using string key and string list

Let say you have something like this
Root
>>child1
    >>>>child1a
    >>>>child1b
>>child2
    >>>>child2a
             >>>>>>child2a(i)
>>child3

and map should be like
Map<Root,List<child1,child2,child3>>
now take child1
>>Map<Child1,List<child1a,child1b>
>>>>now take child1a as child1a will have empty list, drop that from printing
>>>>now take child1b as child1b will have empty list, drop that from printing too
>>Map<Child2,List<child2a>
>>>>now take child2a => Map<Child2a,List<child2a(i)>>....

Comment: I do not understand this >>>> representation at all. Look up [tree structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) to understand how they are commonly stored and manipulated. Yes, you can store a tree as a map-of-maps -- but why would you?